# Minimum of Super Martingale and a Constant is Still a Super Martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, martingales

I am having trouble proving the following statement:

> Let $\alpha>0$ and $M:\Omega\times [0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a super martingale. Then $M\wedge \alpha$ is also a super martingale.

The adaptedness/measurability and the integrability requirements are easy. But I am struggling to show that

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}[M_t\wedge \alpha | \mathscr{F}_s] \le M_s\wedge \alpha \qquad \forall s<t
\end{equation*}

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advanced

Comment: Use $M_t \wedge \alpha \leq M_t$ and the supermartingale property to show that the conditonal expectation is $\leq M_s$. Use $M_t \wedge \alpha \leq \alpha$ to prove that the conditional expectation is $\leq \alpha$.

Comment: Thank you, I was having a mental block and this was extremely helpful!